# sudoedit but no cp

Tags: sudoedit

I have access to a file `/etc/apache/myfile.conf` that gets included in `httpd.conf`.

The permissions are:

`-rw------- 1 root root`

I have `sudoedit` permission to the file but not read!

I can open the file, edit it, but I just want to copy the entire content to take back up.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have regular `sudo`?

Answer (score 4):

You can cheat by setting `$EDITOR` to `cat`
e.g.

```
EDITOR=cat sudoedit /etc/apache/myfile.conf > copy_of_myfile.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

If the only access you have is via sudoedit you could sudoedit the file and write it to a location you do have access to (e.g. /tmp or your home directory):

```
sudoedit /path/file
:w /newpath/newfile
```